# Laravel Eloquent create ignores columns

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent class with the protected set:

```
protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'key', 'value');
```

Yet if I do:

```
Foo::create(array('user_id'=>1, 'key'=> 1, 'value' => 'v'));
```

I get

```
Array
(
[query] => insert into `foo` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?)
[bindings] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2013-09-29 16:32:54
        [1] => 2013-09-29 16:32:54
    )

[time] => 0.42
)
```

On the other hand

```
Foo::insert(array('user_id'=>1, 'key'=> 1, 'value' => 'v'));
```

works flawlessly.

Comment: It looks right.. my guess is that the $fillable variable is not really in place. `Foo::insert` works because it skips all model stuff and works directly with a database query. For debugging purposes, try to dump $fillable after that you've created Foo. You can also for debugging purpose try to unguard it: `Foo::setUnguardState(true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue. I was overriding the `__construct` method in my model object. After I removed my `__construct` method, everything seemed to go back to normal.

I can't say for sure this is what you are experiencing (and this answer is 6 months after your original question), but hopefully this will help someone else who comes across this same issue.